# iOS CLLocationManager desiredAccuracy with multiple apps

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently working on an app which is using location. I'm having a little concern how this desiredAccuracy works? If I set my apps accuracy to `kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters`, and let's say the user use google maps on foreground or some any other app has `kCLLocationAccuracyTenMeters`. So how will this be handled.

Comment: You can verify that by creating two apps with diffferent accuracies and see for yourself

Comment: What is your concern?  The desired accuracy is just that, a desire or want.  You may get better accuracy or you may get worse.  The requested accuracy also determines whether iOS turns on the GPS receiver or not.  If another app has requested 10m accuracy then the GPS will be active and your 100m app would receive more accurate location data.